# I want to login in laravel 5.5 But It is not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am creating a simple login function on my website with a registration feature. The registration feature is functional and users are appearing in the database. However, logging in is not working. When I enter credentials, be it correct or wrong, But It is not working.

laravel 5.5

Please look at my codes.

Middleware/Authenticates.php

Did I write this correctly?

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class Authenticates
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'web')
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check())
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('/');
    }
}
```

LoginController.php

```
public function getLogin()
    {
        if (Auth::guard('web')->check())
        {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return view('login');
    }
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => '/', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogin']);
Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogin']);

Route::group(['middleware', ['authenticates', 'roles']], function (){
    Route::get('/logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogout']);
    Route::get('/dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@dashboard']);
});
```

login.blade.php

```
<form class="login-form" action="{{ route('login') }}" method="post">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <div class="login-wrap">
            <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                <span class="pull-right"> <a href="#"> Forgot Password?</a></span>
            </label>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I want to login. very trying for login but It do not working.

Comment: Try adding the "web" middleware for your routes group. I've had the issue before and this resolved the issue.

Comment: for example: Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', ['authenticates', 'roles']],                    It did not worked.

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan make:auth`?

Comment: No I want to make a simple. from first.